# Beautiful Soup find_all wraps together instead of individually

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, findall

Long story short, I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to replace b tags with strong tags.
Soup takes some input that includes

```
<b>Words:</b> attributes
<b>Other Words:</b> other attributes
```

I have the following python3 code:

```
strong_tag = soup.new_tag("strong")
if(soup.find('b')):
    for b_tag in soup.find_all('b'):
        b_tag.wrap(strong_tag)
```

This outputs

```
attributes
<strong><b>Words:</b><b>Other Words:</b></strong> other attributes
```

instead of

```
<strong><b>Words:</b></strong> attributes
<strong><b>Other Words:</b></strong> other attributes
```

How do I fix this?

I'm assuming that once I can fix this, I can extract() the contents from the b tags, leaving just the strong tags behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div_test="""
<b>Words:</b> attributes
<b>Other Words:</b> other attributes
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test,'html.parser')
for b_tag in soup.find_all('b'):
    b_tag.wrap(soup.new_tag("strong"))
print(soup)
```

this will print:

```
<strong><b>Words:</b></strong> attributes
<strong><b>Other Words:</b></strong> other attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

*simple one hope you would like it*

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag
    mes=""" <b>Words:</b> attributes
    <b>Other Words:</b> other attributes"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mes)

    for a in soup.findAll('b'):
          p = Tag(soup, 'strong')
          a.replaceWith(p)
          p.insert(0, a)

    print soup
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `replace`?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div_test="""<b>Words:</b> attributes
<b>Other Words:</b> other attributes"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test,'lxml')

str(soup).replace("b>","strong>")
```

Output:

```
<html><body><strong>Words:</strong> attributes
<strong>Other Words:</strong> other attributes
</body></html>
```